# How can I use inline SVG multiline text with LTR and RTL support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have created an inline SVG with multiline text.

I want to make it with `LTR` (Left To Right) and `RTL` (Right To Left) support. Is it possible to solve it with SCSS/CSS or with Javascript.

I have added the code and it breaks the svg image on `RTL` view.

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/aspjsplayground/2mt4jum1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#btn").on('click', function() {
    if($('html').is("[dir=rtl]")){
      $('html').attr('dir', 'ltr');
    } else {
     $('html').attr('dir', 'rtl');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  background: #F3F5F6;
}
.center{ text-align: center; }

.Dtls {
  opacity: 1;
}
.clip {
  clip-path: url(#clip-cm);
}

.fill-theme {
  fill: #fff;
}

.fill-theme {
  fill-rule: evenodd;
}

.cardOverlayBg {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.infoTextColor {
  fill: #fefffa;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.textContent {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <a href="javascript:;" id="btn">Toggle LTR - RTL</a>
</div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 954 640">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-cm">
      <rect width="954" height="640"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g id="cm" class="clip cm">
    <g id="ae" class="Dtls" transform="translate(155 20)">
      <rect id="ae-card" class="fill-theme" width="544" height="326" rx="5" transform="translate(19 19)"/>
      <path id="ae-bg" class="cardOverlayBg" d="M19,204H563V341a4,4,0,0,1-4,4H23a4,4,0,0,1-4-4Z"/>
      <text id="ae-text" class="infoTextColor" transform="translate(304.311 244.328)"><tspan x="-129.052" y="0">Lorem, Ipsum (Dolor Sit)</tspan><tspan class="textContent"><tspan x="-133.136" y="19.2">Amet consectetur adipisicing elit adip </tspan><tspan x="-122.504" y="38.4">Deserunt: impedit, reprehenderit</tspan><tspan x="-181.704" y="57.6">reprehenderit ducimus culpa, cumque aperiam cumque</tspan><tspan x="-144.04" y="76.8">dolor illum error | optio inventore ducimus</tspan></tspan></text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Seems fine to me other than for rtl the text origin is on the right so you'd need to adjust that.

Comment: Since you are centering your text. You might want to use `text-anchor="middle"` (and update your text coords appropriately. Then it should not matter whether your text is LTR or RTL.